# what does draw.lines return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

from what I understand draw.lines joins each coordinate that is passed to it, so if we have [A, B, C]
will draw a line from coordinate A to coordinate B and from B to C and if closed is True it draws a line from coordinate A to coordinate C therefore it will always join the first coordinate with the last one its right?

[image]

what i don't understand is what the rect variable returns..
I think that every time I add a new coordinate it returns (starting_point, rectangle_size) where starting point is the first coordinate and the rectangle size is calculated by the distance of the first coordinate with the last one then draw the rectangle with draw.rect
but the reasoning I don't think is right because if I add a coordinate of this type to the list the rectangle remains unchanged

[image]

**CODE:**

```
"""Place a polygone line with the clicks of the mouse."""

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GRAY = (150, 150, 150)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 240))

drawing = False
points = []

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            points.append(event.pos)
            drawing = True
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            drawing = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION and drawing:
            points[-1] = event.pos
    screen.fill(GRAY)
    if len(points)>1:
        rect = pygame.draw.lines(screen, RED, True, points, 3)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rect, 1)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Doesn't the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines) say what the draw.lines returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.draw.lines()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines) returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object that encloses all the points of the line:

> a rect bounding the changed pixels, if nothing is drawn the bounding rect's position will be the position of the first point in the points parameter (float values will be truncated) and its width and height will be 0

The rectangle does not start at any particular point on the line, but is just large enough to enclose all the points along the line.

It returns the same as:

```py
list_x, list_y = zip(*points)
min_x, max_x = min(list_x), max(list_x)
min_y, max_y = min(list_y), max(list_y)
rect = pygame.Rect(min_x, min_y, max_x-min_x, max_y-min_y)
```

Comment: initially I didn't understand what you meant so I tried to figure out for myself the reason why the rectangle remains unchanged and the calculations it performs and I realized that what you wrote was the answer I was looking for thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @User9dazzi91 Sorry, but what is unclear about my answer? What caused the confusion?

Comment: I did not know the functions you used and therefore I could not understand the calculation you had done in fact as you can see in the code I published in the comments I do not use those functions anyway thanks a lot for the help you confirmed that the reasoning was correct with only four lines of code

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines):

> Returns:
> a rect bounding the changed pixels, if nothing is drawn the bounding rect's position will be the position of the first point in the points parameter (float values will be truncated) and its width and height will be 0

Answer (score 0):

**this is the reasoning I made:**

```
import pygame

def minore(lista_coordinate, asse): 
    dimensione = lista_coordinate[0][asse]
    for coordinata in lista_coordinate:
        if coordinata[asse] < dimensione:
            dimensione = coordinata[asse]
    return dimensione

def maggiore(lista_coordinate, asse): 
    dimensione = lista_coordinate[0][asse]
    for coordinata in lista_coordinate:
        if coordinata[asse] > dimensione:
            dimensione = coordinata[asse]
    return dimensione

pygame.init()

schermo = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))

punti = [(100, 100), (200, 100), (200, 50), (150, 80)]

larghezza_minore = minore(punti, 0)
larghezza_maggiore = maggiore(punti, 0)
larghezza_rettangolo = larghezza_maggiore - larghezza_minore

altezza_minore = minore(punti, 1)
altezza_maggiore = maggiore(punti, 1)
altezza_rettangolo = altezza_maggiore - altezza_minore

dimensioni_rettangolo = (larghezza_rettangolo, altezza_rettangolo)
inizio = (larghezza_minore, altezza_minore)

pygame.draw.lines(schermo, (255, 0, 0), True, punti, 3)
pygame.draw.rect(schermo, (0, 255, 0), (inizio, dimensioni_rettangolo), 1) 
pygame.display.update()
```